# Is anyone running the new Next.JS 12 middleware functions on Cloudflare's edge using workers?

Tags: next.js, cloudflare-workers

[Cloudflare's workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com) are an edge based Javascript execution environment. They seem to me to be the perfect place for executing [Next.JS 12's middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) concept.

It surprises me therefore that I can't find much evidence of people doing this despite extensive searching. I'm particularly interested in the idea of using Cloudflare just to execute the middleware and potentially to hold the static elements of a Next.JS build, but then to fall back to a separate (full Node) hosting environment where a `getServerSideProps` or similar needs to be executed.

One of the drawbacks of Next's middleware is that to really take advantage of it, you need to be on Vercel's platform and whilst I've nothing against that platform, I'd like to at least feel like my app is portable.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Are you looking for sources/references/examples on how to integrate both? Or have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I'm looking to see if anyone has proven any concepts around this, if anyone is actively working on it, or if the approach is even viable. `next build` creates a bundle and to make this work I suspect that some parts of that bundle (e.g. the middleware functions) need to go to Cloudflare and others need to go somewhere else.

Comment: Flarereact is probably your best bet. But Vercel's Edge Functions are built on top of Cloudflare Workers so there's some hope